# What algorithm was used for generation of this vector layer?

Tags: arcpy, raster, algorithm, vectorization, arcgis-10.6

[image]

The second image is a raster layer and in the third image obtained vector layer is so accurate.

What algorithm would have been employed?

Normal methods doesn't give nearly equal vectorization.

I applied Raster to polygon conversion and the output is the below image where the green=raster, red=accurate vector,black=result of raster to poly. the red and black both are vectors but are very different.

---

[image]

Green line original raster,
red is the accurate vector,
Black is the outcome of the raster to polygon func.

Comment: Isn't this just [Raster to Polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) with the default SIMPLIFY option? It's not clear why you tagged this with a retired release of ArcGIS. It might not be possible to achieve the same output with such an ancient build of software.

Comment: yes when using Raster to Polygon with the default SIMPLIFY the vector outcome is more generalized. I wanted to tag Arcgis and didn't see the version. I am using the latest version of Arcgis.I have included the picture below.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like [Chaikin smoothing algorithm](http://graphics.cs.ucdavis.edu/education/CAGDNotes/Chaikins-Algorithm/Chaikins-Algorithm.html) and it is very easy to implement:

[image]

It also looks like you have multiple obsolete vertices on straight segments of your green line.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to this part so was unaware of it. Now will try to implement this in Python.